# Gnuplot: subscript and supercript in x and y axis labels

Tags: gnuplot

I am plotting a graph with Volume on the X-axis.

I type the following
set xlabel 'Volume (m^3)'

Obviously I want to show that the units as metres cubed, with the "3" supercripted. How do I this??

Cheers in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By looking at the *Extended ASCII characters*, **superscript three** (third power, or cube) is `alt+252`.

you may also copy/past this:

> ³

For superscript higher than 3, you may need to activate enhanced text mode

```
set termopt enhanced
```

then define your text like the following:

```
Volume (m^{3})
```

Comment: worked perfectly thanks! I actually saw that one could do this elsewhere, but stupidly I misspelled enhanced haha

Comment: Incidentally, Unicode has also `U+2074 SUPERSCRIPT FOUR ⁴` through `U+2079 SUPERSCRIPT NINE ⁹`, as well as `U+2080 SUBSCRIPT ZERO ₀` through `U+2089 SUBSCRIPT NINE ₉`. (Which doesn't necessarily imply any of this works in Gnuplot, I'm still trying...)